# VueJS toggle function on checkbox

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I wonder what the proper way is to toggle a function using a checkbox in VueJS.

```
<input v-model="discount" type="checkbox" name="discount">
```

What I want to do is when the discount is checked I want to update a string in my view displaying the discounted price from normal price to discounted price. Eg $10 to $8

can I simply add this to the checkbox above `@click="toggleDiscount"`

```
toggleDiscount() {
if (this.discount == true) {
        //show discount
      } else {
        //hide discount
      }

}
```

Then inside the `toggleDiscount` I simply check if `discount` is true or false and do the things I have. Or is @click="" not the right thing to use here on a checkbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is where you would typically use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html).

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
 el: "#app",
 data: {
   discount: false,
   price: 10,
   discountedPrice: .8
 },
 computed:{
   computedPrice() { 
     return this.discount ? this.price * this.discountedPrice : this.price
   }
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="discount"> Apply Discount</label> 
  <hr>
  Price: {{computedPrice}}
</div>
```